# Whats the correct way to implement intlinprog matlab function in the given code

Tags: matlab

My code is given below and its not working as intlinprog is not implemented correctly please can someone guide me or help me with this ,it will be much appreciated .what i am trying to implement is minimization of ro mx(which max link utilization and the two main constraints of it are given in the image attached here [Constraint Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enmUj.png)

the error i am getting is

Error using intlinprog (line 121) INTLINPROG requires the following inputs to be of data type double: 'f'.

Error in main (line 111) [x,fval,exitflag] = intlinprog(@objectiveFun,...

code

```
    % delta_edp : if link e on path p used for demand d
      % x_dp  : if path used for demand
      % y_e  : if link e used in any primary path
      % l_dp : the fraction of traffic via path p
      %link

      global hd ce Ye delta_edp X_dp;
      link(1,:)=[1 2];
      link(2,:)=[1 3];
      link(3,:)=[1 4];
      link(4,:)=[2 6];
     link(5,:)=[3 6];
     link(6,:)=[3 7];
     link(7,:)=[4 8];
     link(8,:)=[4 9];
     link(9,:)=[6 10];
     link(10,:)=[7 10];
     link(11,:)=[8 11];
     link(12,:)=[8 12];
     link(13,:)=[9 12];
     link(14,:)=[9 13];
     link(15,:)=[1 5];
     link(16,:)=[5 13];


     %primary path    
      Pd_pr(1,:)=[2, 6, 10];
      Pd_pr(2,:)=[3,7,11];
      Pd_pr(3,:)=[3,7,12];
      Pd_pr(4,:)=[15, 16,0];

      %sencondary path
      Pd_s(1,:)=[1,4,9];
      Pd_s(2,:)=[2,5,9];
      Pd_s(3,:)=[3,8,13];
      Pd_s(4,:)=[3,8,14];

      path=[Pd_pr;Pd_s];

      %link capacity
      ce=[50 50 200 50 50 50 150 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50];

      %demand
      demand=[1 10;1 11;1 12;1 13];


      %associated flow values for demand
      hd=[50 50 50 50];

      %value of X_dp
      X_dp=zeros(4,8);

      for jj=1:4
          for kk=1:8
              demandStart=demand(jj,1);
              demandEnd=demand(jj,2);
              pathStart=path(kk,1);
              linkStart=link(pathStart,1);
              pathEnd=path(kk,3);
              if pathEnd==0
                  pathEnd=path(kk,2);
              end

              linkEnd=link(pathEnd,2);
              if pathEnd==0
                  pathEnd=path(kk,2);
              end
              if demandStart==linkStart && demandEnd==linkEnd
                  X_dp(jj,kk)=1;
              end
          end
      end

       X_dp1=reshape(X_dp,1,[]); 

      %value of delat_edp
      delta_edp=zeros(16,4,8);



      for ii=1 : 16
          for jj=1: 4
              for kk=1:8
                  for nn=1:3
                      if path(kk,nn)==ii && X_dp(jj,kk)==1
                          delta_edp(ii,jj,kk)=1;
                      end
                  end
              end
          end
      end

      %value of Ye
      Ye=zeros(16,1);
      for ii=1:16
          for kk=1:4
              for nn=1:3
                  if Pd_pr(kk,nn)==ii
                      Ye(ii)=1;
                  end
              end
          end
      end



lb = zeros(1,32);
ub=1;

options = optimoptions('intlinprog','Display','iter');
intcon=@constraint;
[x,fval,exitflag]=intlinprog(@objectiveFun,... 
  32,[],[],lb,ub,intcon,options);

l_dp=reshape(x,4,8)

min_romax=fval



function [c,ceq] =constraint(X_dp1)
    global hd ce Ye delta_edp;

      %first constrain 
      X_dp=reshape(X_dp1,4,8);

          X_dp=reshape(X_dp1,4,8);
      for ii=1 : 16
          ro(ii)=0;
          for jj=1 : 4 %demand
              for kk=1:8
                  if delta_edp(ii,jj,kk)==1
                        ro(ii)=ro(ii)+hd(jj)*X_dp(jj,kk);
                  end
              end
          end
          ro(ii)=ro(ii)/ce(ii);
      end
      ro_max=max(ro);


   for ii=1:16
       A(ii)=0;
       C(ii)=1;
       for jj=1:4
           for kk=1:8
               A(ii)=A(ii)+hd(jj)*delta_edp(ii,jj,kk)*X_dp(jj,kk);
           end

       end
       B(ii)=ce(ii);
       C(ii)=C(ii)*(1-Ye(ii));
   end

c=A-B;
c=round(c);
ceq=(A./B)-C-ro_max;
ceq=round(ceq);

%% objective function
function  f=objectiveFun(l_dp1)
      global hd ce delta_edp
      l_dp=reshape(l_dp1,4,8);
      for ii=1 : 16
          ro(ii)=0;
          for jj=1 : 4 %demand
              for kk=1:8
                  if delta_edp(ii,jj,kk)==1
                        ro(ii)=ro(ii)+hd(jj)*l_dp(jj,kk);
                  end
              end
          end
          ro(ii)=ro(ii)/ce(ii);
      end
      ro_max=max(ro);
  f=ro_max
```

Comment: 'f' should be a vector or array, insert `whos f` in your code right before the call to intlinprog and see what happens. Also, I got an error that f is undefined when I tried to run your code.

Comment: Hi I made a few changes to the code and now if u could guide me it would be really nice

Comment: The documentation states that f is "specified as a vector of doubles representing the objective function, f'*x". `f` must be a vector, not a function

Comment: So the function result needs to be stored in a vector ?